error when using textls with fonts with spaces in the name with lualatex/texlive2024
Up until now, using the full name for fonts with lualatex worked fine in all cases. However since the update to TeXLive 2024, it produces an error when using \textls[]{}.
The following code produces this error
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: Font "kernfactor=-0.005;Libertinus Serif at 10.95pt" not found....xmf-dist/tex/lu
atex/luaotfload/fontloader-basics-gen.lua:156: bad argument #2 to 'find_file' (
invalid option '95pt').
<to be read again>
edef
l.14 \textls[-5]{\blindtext}

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\textls[-5]{\blindtext}

\end{document}

Using \setmainfont{LibertinusSerif} works as expected. Without using \textls[]{}, both syntax work fine.
I am not sure where to report the issue though: fontspec? microtype? luaoftload?

see https://github.com/latex3/fontspec/issues/509

Thanks @UlrikeFischer
