Error with TeX Gyre Pagella for ClassicThesis
Consider the following example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}

With an updated major TeX distribution, when compiling with LuaLaTeX, one would get the following errors:
Font \TU/TeXGyrePagella(0)/m/n/10/80ls=name:kernfactor=0.08;TeX Gyre Pagella not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
edef

bad argument #2 to 'find_file' (invalid option '08;tex gyre pagella').
<to be read again> 
edef

With XeLaTeX there would be more errors.
This appears to be new errors introduced by certain recent update, since my old documents could compile without issue by March 2024. May I ask what might be causing the errors and how might one fix it? Thanks!

related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/717061/36296 ?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the links, seems to be essentially the same issue, and it seems to have been fixed in the dev version. I don't quite know how might one enable the fix at this time though.

To test with the dev version, you can download the dev branch from https://github.com/schlcht/microtype/tree/dev , unpack the .dtx file and put the resulting files in your current working directory

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you. I just tried and everything works now. I might better keep my question here as it might help those people encountering the same issue using ClassicThesis by now, but feel free to mark my question as a duplicate.

The problem is: we can't add a duplicate link to the top of questions until at least one of them gets an answer. Another duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/724715/36296

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz You are really good at searching for questions! To be frank I wasn't able to find anything when posting this question. Are there perhaps some tricks that you could share?

I found the first question by searching for the error message: https://www.ecosia.org/search?method=index&q=fontloade+r-basics-gen.lua%3A156%3A+bad+argument+%232+to+%27find_file And once I knew that the problem is microtype I just scrolled through the first few questions in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microtype

As a workaround, you can use the palatino=false option and manually load the fonts without spaces in their names:
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{TeXGyrePagella}         
\linespread{1.05} % a bit more for Palatino
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeXGyrePagellaMath}

\usepackage[palatino=false]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}


As @samcarter pointed out in the comment, it turns out that this is actually an issue with microtype already dealt with here: https://github.com/schlcht/microtype/issues/35. To make it work as of now, one could download the dev version of microtype (https://github.com/schlcht/microtype/tree/dev), compile the microtype.ins, and copy every generated file to the working folder. The document should now compile without error.
